# Can I call the Multi Channel Funnel mcf from within Apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics

I was working through [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/reporting-apps-script) tutorial and got things working.

I then tried to edit it to obtain data from the Google Analytics multi channel funnel:

This works using the core reporting api (`Analytics.Data.Ga.get(...`)
    function getReportDataForProfile(profile) { // I have defined my profile id earlier

```
  var startDate = getLastNdays(750);   // 2 weeks (a fortnight) ago.
  var endDate = getLastNdays(0);      // Today.

  var optArgs = {
    'dimensions': 'ga:medium', // Comma separated list of dimensions.
    'start-index': '1',
    'max-results': '10000'                     // Display the first 10000 results.
    //'sampling-level': 'higher-precision',
  };

  // Make a request to the API.
  var results = Analytics.Data.Ga.get( // mcf for multi channel api, Ga for core
      profile,                    // Table id (format ga:xxxxxx).
      startDate,                  // Start-date (format yyyy-MM-dd).
      endDate,                    // End-date (format yyyy-MM-dd).
      'ga:sessions', // Comma seperated list of metrics.
      optArgs);

  if (results.getRows()) {
    return results;

  } else {
    throw new Error('No views (profiles) found');
  }
}
```

That block is slightly edited from the tutorial but works as expected - I get data. I tried to modify it to get data from the mcf:

This does not work. Why not?

```
function getReportDataForProfile(profile) {

  var startDate = getLastNdays(750);   // 2 weeks (a fortnight) ago.
  var endDate = getLastNdays(0);      // Today.

  var optArgs = {
    'dimensions': 'mcf:medium', // Comma separated list of dimensions.
    'start-index': '1',
    'max-results': '10000'                     // Display the first 10000 results.
    //'sampling-level': 'higher-precision',
  };

  // Make a request to the API.
  var results = Analytics.Data.mcf.get( // mcf for multi channel api, Ga for core
      profile,                    // Table id (format ga:xxxxxx).
      startDate,                  // Start-date (format yyyy-MM-dd).
      endDate,                    // End-date (format yyyy-MM-dd).
      'mcf:firstInteractionConversions', // Comma seperated list of metrics.
      optArgs);

  if (results.getRows()) {
    return results;

  } else {
    throw new Error('No views (profiles) found');
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the error?  There only syntax error I can see is sampling-level is supposed to be samplingLevel, but you have that commented out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you used mcf instead Mcf:

```
var results = Analytics.Data.Mcf.get
```

Hope this helps.